# SparklyR Lubridate

Tags: sparklyr

A code was still working yesterday but no longer works. Below is the code and the error message. Someone can help me?

```
tbl(connexion, "donnees1") %>% 
  select(date_heure_debut) %>% 
sdf_schema()
$date_heure_debut
$date_heure_debut$name
[1] "date_heure_debut"

$date_heure_debut$type
[1] "StringType

tbl(connexion, "donnees1") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    annee_debut = lubridate::year(date_heure_debut)
    ) %>%
  sdf_register("donnees1")

Error in lubridate::year(date_heure_debut) : 
  object 'date_heure_debut' not found
```